# Understanding direct and semi direct products through notations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Can someone please help to understand and identify the following groups?

> 1. $G_1 = \langle a, b \mid a^{p^2} = b^q = 1, b a b^{-1} = a^i, \operatorname{ord}_{p^2}(i) = q \rangle$.
> 2. A family of groups given by,
>      $$
>      \langle
>        a, b, c
>      \mid
>        a^p = b^p = c^q = 1,
>        c a c^{-1} = a^i,
>        c b c^{-1} = b^{i^t},
>        ab = ba,
>        \operatorname{ord}_p(i) = q
>      \rangle
>    $$
>      where $p, q$—distinct primes, $p > q$ and $q \mid p - 1$.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBiHD.jpg).)

Can the first group be written as,
$$
  \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \rtimes_\varphi \mathbb{Z}_q
$$
and the second group as,
$$
  (\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_q.
$$
What does $\operatorname{ord}_{p^2}(i) = q$, $\operatorname{ord}_p(i) = q$ mean?

Comment: $\text{ord}_{p}(i)=q$ means that the multiplicative order of $i$ modulo $p$ is $q$

Comment: The answers to your first two questions are both yes.

Comment: Thanks. Can I regard them as an extension of the semidirect product between $Z_p$ and $Z_q$?

Comment: Can I say that the above two semidirect products are the direct products?

Comment: No they are not direct products. If they were direct products then they would be abelian groups, which they are not.

Comment: Can someone please explain how to obtain the commutator subgroup for the above mentioned groups?

Comment: Please help me with this question

Comment: Can I say that the order of the commutator subgroup should be either $p$ or $p^2$?