# Commutator subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}_q$ with $p,q$ distinct primes

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Can someone please help to find the commutator subgroup and its order for the group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}_q$, where $p, q$ are distinct primes?

Comment: This is a group with explicit structure. Why not list all commutators and see what subgroup do they generate?

Comment: What is $\varphi$?

Comment: This is the first group [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894864/understanding-direct-and-semi-direct-products-through-notations), right? For the commutator I saw a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894900/on-the-order-of-derived-subgroup).

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry I missed mentioning the conditions of p,q. If those conditions are satisfied how will it be... Please help more

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't see how you can say what group it is without knowing what $\varphi$ is (well I guess there are only two possibilities).

Comment: @DerekHolt Indeed, how can I know this without $\phi$? I noticed that Angelika had a question before, and most likely "meant" the group discussed there. So a continuation, in a way. Did you see the former question?

Comment: @DietrichBurde In fact there are only two possibilities. Either $\varphi$ is trivial and $[G,G]=1$, or $\varphi$ is nontrivial and $[G,G] = Z_{p^2}$. I suspect that there was a tacit assumption that $\varphi  \ne 1$.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do not work with the definition of the commutator subgroup directly, but rather the equivalent definition: it is the smallest normal subgroup $N$ (w.r.t. inclusion) such that the factor group $G/N$ is commutative.

The $p$-Sylow $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is a normal subgroup such that the factor group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{q}$, hence is commutative. 
So the commutatator subgroup is contained in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$. 
The only thing you need to check is if there is a normal subgroup inside $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$. It would be closed under conjugation by an element of order $q$. 
If there is such a thing, you still have to check the factor group. It is easy to figure out the isomorphism type of it.

Comment: There is a normal subgroup. i.e. a group of order $p$. But if we consider a group of order $p$ to be the commutator subgroup, the order of the factor group will be $pq$. Then we can't take the factor group as isomorphic to $Z_q$, right?

Comment: Whether or not there is a normal subgroup of order $p$ depends on how you define $\varphi$...

Comment: But can I say that order of commutator subgroup should be either $p$ or $p^2$ for what ever the map phi?

Comment: Think about the possibilities for $\varphi$, and you will see the answer yourself. As there are commutative groups of order $p^2q$ (also of the form you put, when $\varphi$ is the trivial homomorphism), whose commutator subgroup is trivial, there is surely that third possibility. 
I have given you more than enough hints, you should start thinking on your own now.